# Show navigation tag on grails

Tags: grails

I want to show the actual page where i am in a gsp.
For example if i have a menu like this:

**Menu1**: *Submenu1*,*submenu2*,*submenu3*

**Menu2**: *Submenu4*: *Submenu5*(*action1* that redirects to *Submenu6*)

**Menu3**: *Submenu6*

, when I go to "*Submenu5*" I want to show in a textbox "*Menu2* > *Submenu4* > *Submenu5*".

Then if I do "*action1*" it shows "*Menu2* > *Submenu4* > *Submenu5* > *Submenu6*", but if i go "*Submenu6*" from the "*Menu3*" it shows "*Menu3* > *Submenu6*".

Do i need to have a tag in EVERY gsp and concat it every time i change from page to page?
Does anyone know another way to make this?

Is there any plugin to make this easy?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in that [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin), it works fine for me.